# Alternative to HTML to PDF converter?

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I've been using the Winnovative HTML to PDF converter for a few years, but I've noticed the quality can be impared because the images etc have first had to be rendered in HTML before being converted into a PDF format.

Winnovative have another option where you can add objects to the PDF Converter before outputting the result, but as this allows you to add HTML elements, I imagine this works in a similar way to the HTML to PDF converter (in terms of rendering).

Is there an alternative to this so that I can generate a PDF in my ASP.NET Web Application without it first having to be rendered as HTML?

I'm looking for the most high quality option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library. It has an object representation of whole PDF document so it will allow you to add any elements you need without translating it from html elements. It also allows you to convert html to pdf, but of course you can do it manually instead by building PDF document from basic blocks...

If you will use version `4.x` then it's free to use in commercial projects (LGPL license). Version `5.x`  is avaible on Affero General Public License so I believe you have to buy it to use in commercial projects, but the features I've described are avaible in the `4.x`version

Answer (score 0):

try http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

it's lightning fast in comparison to iTextSharp.

For step by step installation check out these articles:

http://www.megustaulises.com/2012/12/mvcnet-convert-html-to-pdf-with-pechkin.html

http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-pass-html-as-a-string-using-wkhtmltopdf/

And this manual:

http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html